# Como fazer uma configuração basica no arquivo persistence.xml para acessar um banco de dados no SQL Server 2008?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

Procurei a respeito de como configurar o arquivo `persistence.xml` de uma forma básica, porem, fiquei mais confuso ainda em relação a esta configuração.

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer uma configuração básica no arquivo `persistence.xml` de acordo com o **JPA** e o **Hibernate** para acessar um banco de dados no **SQL Server 2008**?

---

## Informações referente ao banco de dados:

Minha String de conexão:

```
"Data Source=CARVALHO-PC\\LOGIXMINESYSTEM;Initial Catalog=TarefaExemplo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=minhasenha"
```

O banco possui uma única tabela chamada `tarefas` com os campos `id int`, `descricao VARCHAR(50)`, `finalizado int` e `data_finalizado DATETIME`.

## Informações referente a estrutura do projeto e da aplicação:

Já adicionei todas as bibliotecas (JARs) referentes ao Hibernate e o JPA e também o driver JDBC para o SQL Server.

E a estrutura do projeto esta da seguinte forma:

```
...\EXEMPLOHIBERNATE\SRC
├───exemplohibernate
├───META-INF
└───model
```

Sendo que dentro do pacote model existe uma única classe, classe `Tarefa`:

```
package model;

import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
/**
 * @author Dener
 */

@Entity
@Table(name="tarefas")
public class Tarefa {
    
    @GeneratedValue    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    private String descricao;
    private boolean finalizado;
    
    @Column(name = "data_finalizado", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Calendar dataFinalizacao;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public boolean isFinalizado() {
        return finalizado;
    }

    public void setFinalizado(boolean finalizado) {
        this.finalizado = finalizado;
    }

    public Calendar getDataFinalizacao() {
        return dataFinalizacao;
    }

    public void setDataFinalizacao(Calendar dataFinalizacao) {
        this.dataFinalizacao = dataFinalizacao;
    }
    
}
```

Esta é a classe que tem as anotações para o Framework. E os outros pacotes não contem classes ainda.

Nota:

> A aplicação de exemplo é para plataforma desktop e a IDE que estou usando e o NetBeans.

Comment: Tenho um modelo de persistense q fiz pra testar no javadb ou mysql, será que serve? To sem SQL  server aqui pra testar.

Comment: @DiegoF eu ja consegui solucionar o problema, usei um assistente do NetBeans para criar o arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar isso:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence-unit name="tarefas">

     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

     <class>model.Tarefa</class>

           <properties>
               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"></property>
               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TarefaExemplo"></property>
               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"></property>
               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="minhaSenha"></property>
           </properties>
       </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```